# Unselectable text above HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I'm looking for a way to make text ***completely*** unselectable. I have a set of HTML5 videos with text above them. When you hover over the videos, it plays the video. When I place text above the video, it causes the video to stop if the user hovers over the text.

Is there any possible way of making the text almost transparent, so that it doesn't cause the video to stop playing? I've tried the following:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: -moz-none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
cursor:default;
```

But these styles just stop the user from selecting the text. You can view an [example of the problem here](http://www.watchthis.limited).

I couldn't find any answers that deal with this particular problem, so I opened up a new query. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add pointer-events: none to the text element, in your case to .overlay :)

```
.overlay{
    pointer-events: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.9em;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0.8;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #000000;
}
```

Comment: Glad that I could help. You can now accept the answer so the question can be closed :)